# Podemos reformular a pergunta "Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8"?

Tags: debate

[Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8)

Essa pergunta já serviu para tantas duplicatas que eu nem me arriscaria chutar um valor, mas o mérito é todo das respostas e não da pergunta. Na verdade, a qualidade da pergunta não justificaria ter a quantidade de votos que possui.

Não seria interessante para a comunidade reformularmos a pergunta de uma forma melhor estruturada, dada a utilidade dela dentro do site? A pergunta melhor estruturada provavelmente também seria melhor indexada e, assim, ficaria mais fácil de encontrá-la nas buscas.

Comment: Dado que o autor não teve mais participação no site além da pergunta, seria interessante converter a pergunta para wiki?

Answer (score 4):

Eu sou a favor de elaborar uma nova pergunta sim, mas uma pergunta 'centrada' ou melhor, bem definida sobre o assunto, na verdade eu como autor de uma das resposta cheguei em pensar em reformular até a resposta, porque ela ficou 'completa', mas ficou uma verdadeira salada. O problema é que a resposta começou como uma coisa e as indagações do autor e de outros visitantes me fizeram sentir a necessidade explicar o *beabá*, com isto realmente não tive como separar um tempo para organizar de uma forma razoável.

Considero que minha própria resposta tem muito texto, mas poderia ser melhor aproveitado e até de forma mais simples e ainda sim atingir todos pontos necessários como:

- O que são os codecs
- Porque 2 codecs não funcionam em um local só
- Configurar o HTML (ou nos headers HTTP)
- Salvar os documentos no codec
- E separar a parte sobre conexão+codec com diferentes bancos em diferentes perguntas (porque existem várias APIs e bancos e ainda por cima existem diferentes linguagens)

> Em edição